# gapi auth2 init failing with "Uncaught ReferenceError: auth2 is not defined"

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-signin, google-oauth, google-api-js-client

I am trying to implement Google signin with custom button. I am using Angular 1. I have loaded ***platform.js*** asynchronously as well as synchronously.

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
```

I am loading auth2 in the controller of my popup.

```
gapi.load('auth2', function() {
  auth2 = gapi.auth2.init({
    client_id: '<my_client_id>',
    cookiepolicy: 'single_host_origin'
  });

    // attachSignin(document.getElementById('google_signin'));
});
```

In the console, gapi and auth2 are both defined. The code actually fails in the init function of auth2, which I couldn't debug. Any help is much appreciated.

Following is the stack from console

[image: Error stack from console]

Comment: Which **exactly** is line 31 of `login.controller.js`?

Comment: auth2 = gapi.auth2.init({...

Comment: I'd remove the `async` and `defer` attributes from the Google `<script>` tag

Comment: I tried that. It didn't work.

Comment: Is the `auth2` variable defined anywhere? If not, then you're trying to implicitly define a global variable which will fail under strict mode. You should have `var auth2` or `const auth2` or `let auth2` somewhere in your code

Comment: Oh! That did it. I was in strict mode. I removed strict mode. Thank you so much! I don't know how I would have reached to this conclusion.

Comment: Don't remove strict mode. Fix your bad code instead

Comment: Yes. Was just experimenting.